# Is it safe to call foreach on empty php arrays in PHP 5.4?

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.4

As i remember, before i always had to check count($array) before making a foreach.
From that times i always make this doublecheck, and wanted to know, does it make sense nowdays with php 5.4?

I've set error_reporting to E_ALL and executed following script:

```
$x = [];

foreach($x as $y) {
    var_dump($y);
}
```

and got no notice (as i remember, previously, perhaps it was php5.3) i was getting notice.

Is it safe now using foreach on array, that is empty?

Comment: It was always safe to enumerate an empty array. What notice did you receive before? Perhaps it was due to some other issue?

Comment: nope, i'm sure, i remember i was getting some notice about empty array O_o, don't remember it's text :(

Comment: Iterating an empty array has always been safe.  If the array doesn't exist or is `null` though, that's another story.

Comment: Ok.. now i'll be very sure, thanks!

Comment: Was it `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`? Wouldn't show on an array but would if you have defined the var but not as an array.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As long as it's an array, there's no need to check the amount of items in it. Just make sure to pass it an actual iterable object: for example, don't pass it random objects or `NULL`.

But yes, `foreach([] as $nothing) {}` is safe.